# adding libraries in jnlp file

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have an application that is packaged as a jar file that has 249 libs in another folder. These libs are from jmonkey and glassfish. I currently have no libs as resources in the jnlp and, as expected, it does not run stating it cannot find a class in JMonkey. Do I have to list each jar in the lib file separately as a resource or is there a way of adding the folder to the classpath so to speak. Also do I have to sign each jar file with the same signature I used for my application?

[edit-update]
I am at the point where I have deployed an ear file that contains my appclient.jar file and I can run it from the cmd with java -jar appclient.jar and the libs are in a folder in the same directory. On this attempt I haven't signed anything yet but I fail before I get to that point as launching from the web page with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" >
    <information>
        <title>Maze Runner</title>
        <vendor>Vendor</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="http://localhost:8080/applications/mazeApp/mazeAppClient.jar"
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="Maze Runner"
         main-class="Main"
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

I have tried the href both with/without the applications component in the address
and the button as:

```
<script>
// using JavaScript to get location of JNL
 // file relative to HTML page
 var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/res/mazeApp.jnlp";
 deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.7.0');
</script>
```

I get the error unable to launch application and the wrapped exception is FileNotFoundException with the path in the jnlps href.

So I think the javascript is fine and calling the jnlp but the href in there is not pointing where I think it is. The path on the disk is:

```
/home/lg/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/mazeApp/mazeAppClient.jar
```

I thought localhost:8080/mazeApp would get me where I need to be.

[edit-update] when I run

```
> javaws http://localhost:8080/mazeWeb/res/mazeApp.jnlp
```

I get

> Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.Error:
>   Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.   at
>   java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1118)

[edit-update]After a bit of googling it seems that my first problem is that $CLASSPATH is not set. I will be checking my install later.

Comment: This can be done using the manifest file in the jar, with the ClassPath entry. I would recommend doing this using Maven with the dependency plugin, or some other build tool.
http://maven.apache.org/  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

Comment: This is partly what I don't understand here as I have that. They are all listed in the manifest, MANIFEST.MF, with class-path and all files are listed as signed.

Comment: Do the entries on the ClassPath field in the manifest have the directory they are stored in as a prefix (ie something like ./lib/myjardep.jar)? If they dont, that's your issue. I typically use maven-jar-plugin and the classpathPrefix property to prepend that value to the classpath entries.

Comment: They did have them I have just overwritten them but when I ran it last the folder was prepended. They are in the same folder will that matter when I get them to gf?